# Create volumes only from docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

We have various docker-compose files that create a service infrastructure. My question is if it is possible to only create the volumes defined in the compose file without creating the containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible without starting any services.

command can be provided like this.

```
docker-compose up --no-start --no-deps
```

Or it's possible to specify individual volume.

```
docker-compose up --no-deps -d --volume <volume-name>
```

Comment: Ignore my previous comment please. It was a different mistake on my end, the first one works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `docker-compose.override.yml` file with invalid entrypoints or different image (use a small template image) for those containers, that way they'll die immediately.

docker-compose.override.yml:

```
<conatiner-name>:
        image: hello-world
        command: "/hello"
        restart: "no"
```